# How to make react load bootstrap classes, className=""

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

i installed bootstrap and create-react-app with npm on my machine. Then I created a new react-app with this first component counter.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
 class Counter extends Component {    
  state = {    
    name: test    
  };   
render() {  
 return ( 
  <div>
    <span> className="badge badge-primary">{this.state.name)}</span>    
    <button>Increment</button>    
  </div>
 );
}

export default Counter;
```

instead of the badges i get `className="badge badge-primary">test` on my site
I imported bootstrap css and the component in my index.js where the component is rendered:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import Counter from './components/counter';

ReactDOM.render(
 <React.StrictMode>
  <Counter />
 </React.StrictMode>,
 document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I googled the problem and tried configuring my webpack.config.js. That didn't really help but I'm not really sure if I made the right changes. Did any of you experience the same problem before?

Comment: why did you update you're question to fix your issues ? Now your question didn't have any sense for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo on your `span` tag (you close it 2 times)

Replace:
`<span> className="badge badge-primary">`

By:
`<span className="badge badge-primary">`

---

Also, you're closing a `)` just after the `this.state.name` who wasn't opened before, Be sure you want it.

Replace:
`{this.state.name)}`

By:
`{this.state.name}`

---

**Updated**

Ok, So you have others problemes, here a final version with all fixes: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-sun-qtwep?file=/src/App.js:0-306

What did I change:

- You forgot the final `}` in order to close you component (after closing your render() function)
- The `test` variable didn't exist so I replace the `name:test` by `name:'test'`

It's working fine now =]

Comment: I fixed the typos but the problem still presists

Comment: Edited to fix others issues

Comment: Thank you very much. it works now, I feel a bit dumb now.